# Efficient random rectangle placement with no overlaps

Tags: algorithm, optimization, overlap, rectangles

I wrote an algorithm to randomly place X=1,000 rectangles without any overlaps. Rectangles have a random width and height between about 5 and 50, and a random x and y between about 0 and 1000. Here's my existing algorithm:

1. obtain a random candidate rectangle
2. loop over all the existing rectangles that have already been placed and check to make sure that the candidate doesn't overlap any of them (loop breaks on first overlap)
3. if there's an overlap in 2 then discard candidate and don't increment the count, if there's no overlap then draw the candidate rectangle and increment the count (so that it reaches X)

My overlap check for two rectangles is this JavaScript:

```
const noOverlap = testRect.rbp.y < candidateRect.ltp.y ||
    candidateRect.rbp.y < testRect.ltp.y ||
    testRect.ltp.x > candidateRect.rbp.x ||
    candidateRect.ltp.x > testRect.rbp.x
```

rbp is right bottom point of the rectangle and ltp is left top point.

When the count gets close to X, there can be 30,000 discards in a row. So, I have put in an optimization to reduce the rectangle size when there are a bunch of discards in a row.

Can I do any better?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a hierarchical approach of generating an array of one rectangle of size 1000x1000, where the first element must fit into.

```
// +----------+   ->  +----+-----+
// |          |       |   A|     |
// | +--+     |       +-+--+     |  
// | |N |     |       |B|  |D    |
// | +--+     |       | +--+-----+
// |          |       | |C       |
// +----------+       +-+--+-----+
```

After the candidate N is found to fit in the canvas, the rectangle is split into four smaller rectangles A,B,C,D.

The next rectangle to be inserted must fit into either A,B,C,D, or the union of AB, BC, CD or DA. This is ensured by recursing either to a single node or to recursing to both nodes and finding no collision.

After no collision is found, one unfortunately needs to recurse again and mark the area used -- it can't be done on the first pass, since in the worst case the candidate may fit say 120 rectangles out of 128, but not all -- converting recursion to iteration with fifo would allow early exit.

If perfect randomness is not required, the same technique can be applied by simply selecting randomly one of the areas A,B,C,D and following the tree to the leaf and inserting the new rectangle there indiscriminately. In this case one should also how each of the rectangles are split to smaller rectangles, as an unintended structure may appear (lines where the rectangles concentrate or where they are missing).

Comment: This is a novel idea, but I don't think you will meet the requirement that the rectangles are of random size or placement, as the placement of further rectangles reduces the size/placement of acceptable neighbors in other zones.  consider the placement of even a tiny rectangle bottom left corner at 20, 20 (with 0,0 at bottom left of grid).  You have now created an artificial "boundary" along the bottom and left axis for large rectangles and also place a no-drop zone that would preclude a rectangle from straddling the line.  It would look very "regional"

Comment: This would be the case for the last paragraph; I don't have a proof, but one should be able to place a new rectangle that crosses boundaries of AB, BC, CD or DA. When this happens, the rectangle is further divided into only 3 or 2 regions (or the other regions will have a zero area) and they will never fail a test for placement.

This has the problem of non guaranteed insertion. Without some tweaking of parameters the failure rate approaches 25% per iteration.